# amazon adsystem not working (not getting any respsonse)

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

A few days ago the following code worked for me but now I am not getting any response.

Can someone help?

https://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?callback=search_callback&TemplateId=PubStudio&MarketPlace=US&Operation=ItemSearch&InstanceId=0&dataType=jsonp&ServiceVersion=20070822&Keywords=B097TVLB4F

In response to the above link I got a response in XML format.
I am trying to get amazon ASIN number detail, e.g. Name, image and price, rating and other details.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _the following code worked for me_ Pardon me, but I don't see any code. Are you referring to the link that you posted in your question?

Comment: I mean link i gave is not working. It was working few days back

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _In response to the above link I got a response in XML format_ [Edit] your question and post the XML response you are getting (as text and not as a screen capture). Saying _not working_ doesn't help solve your problem.

Comment: I have a very similar problem (it causes images to be fetched from amazon-adsystem.com not to be displayed/appear to be broken). It seems that the domain "amazon-adsystem.com" is no longer recognized. For example, if you ping it, the response is "No address associated with hostname" and `dig` cannot resolve it (provide URLs), as it can, for example with amazon.com.

Comment: you  able to find any solution of this problem?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. There was another question, very similar, and I commented there too but unfortunately, it was removed "for reasons of moderation". FWIW, the other question was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77793273/fetching-amazon-product-image-by-asin-and-market-place-id-not-working .

Comment: This might be related to this: https://www.reddit.com/r/Affiliatemarketing/comments/17seafh/amazon_affiliates_doesnt_give_a_damn/